# Receive android internal intent Broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent

What happens when we click the default message app in android.I mean does it broadcast an intent? Actually I am trying to make an app that will ask for a password in an new activity when user clicks on message icon and is redirected to list of messages only if password is correct.But my activity is not shown.Here is how I am trying to do it.Added a receiver in manifest.

```
    <receiver android:name="Receiver">
      <intent-filter android:priority="100">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT">
      </action>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:mimeType = "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" />
      </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

Comment: I am new to android.So if I have any wrong concept plz help me

Comment: You should explain it a little better. But I'll try to explain a few things:
When an SMS message is received, a new intent is broadcast, and that intent can be processed by one or more apps that are interested in that intent.
Now, what i didn't understood was this: 
1- Is your app trying to intercept / store SMS messages?
2- Are you trying to launch an activity when a message is received?

Comment: I want the app to work like a message locker.So when user clicks on message icon of android my app should ask for a password.My app is not trying to intercept or store message.what i can't figure out is how to know when user clicks on default message app of android?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about "launching" an activity. Typically that is done with an intent created as such:

```
Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
launch.setPackage("com.your.package.name");
startActivity(launch);
```

Because the package name is set, you cannot intercept this intent. It is not broadcast to any receiver.

If you write a launcher app, you could intercept such a launch request and launch a different app in front of it. But it would not really be possible to prevent users from side-stepping this by returning to the default Android launcher.

However, there are several other means of "launching" the "default" SMS app. For example, an app that requests an SMS be sent through the default SMS app will create an intent like this:

```
Intent launch = new Intent("android.intent.action.SENDTO");
```

There are several others as well. And your app can register an activity for these intent in the manifest like this:

```
    <activity                                     
              android:name="com.your.package.name.MyMessageActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
       </intent-filter>
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In Android KitKat a user must actually set your app as the "Default SMS App" in order for it to be able to write to the SMS provider/database and also to receive the "SMS_DELIVER" intent. In all versions of Android, any app can register for the "SMS_RECEIVED" intent but in KitKat+ it cannot be aborted, like in earlier versions.

You may notice that one filter specified above is similar to yours - using mimeType `"vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"` as a "DEFAULT" action. This places your app as one option for the user to "Complete Action Using" when, for example, they select a contact they want to message.

If you do all of this, then your activity can require a password in order to "view" messages. However, you should be aware that unless you are using a separate data store for the messages, all SMS can be read through the MMS-SMS provider (assuming the app has requested permission to do so).

Comment: Thanks!.. But is there a way my app can know when user clicks on default message app to view all messages so that it can ask for a password?Like it happens when we lock the messaging app in some phones.

Comment: I've edited my response - you can't stop another app from launching without being an app launcher app.

Comment: So there is no way to implement what I am trying to do??

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible, please see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21469133/2452039

You cannot prevent native applications from opening with an outside app. The only thing you could do would be to intercept incoming messages, preventing them from reaching the SMS app inbox, and store them in your application, and there you could prevent them from opening. I must warn you that since API level 19 that is no longer possible...